# how to have UITableView sitting on top of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to achieve the following effect
- UIImageView placing at bottom
- UITableView placing on top of UIImageView and covering portion of the UIImageView
- when pull-down the UITableView, the rest of the UIImageView will appear accordingly.

I coded in the following way inside a UIViewController

```
[self.view addSubview:[self myImageView]]; // CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 240.0f)
[self.view addSubview:[self myTableView]]; // CGRectMake(0.0f, 140.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)
```

But visually, when the table view is pulled down, it'll be like the tableview was sitting beneath the image view and getting pulled out of the image view, instead of what I wanted to achieve above.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

A UITableView doesn't display what's behind it in the subview hierarchy. It has a background, and you're not technically dragging a long list up and down in and out of view, but simple dragging what's displayed in a set frame which is always the same height. When dragging too far up or down, the background of the table view is displayed*.

There are two solutions to your problem..

You can add the image as a background of your table's view (using your object names above):

```
// nil by default (but has a color if nil)
[[self myTableView] setBackgroundView:[self myImageView]];
```

or you can make the table view's background color transparent, showing any subviews in the background:

```
[[self myTableView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

In your case, since the myImageView frame is not filling up the entire screen frame, the latter solution is probably the best one, but just realize that the area where there isn't an image will be whatever back-most background color is (UIViewController's background or UIWindow, depending on your setup).

Hope this helps!

*Unless setting a header or footer view, but this is part of UIScrollView, which UITableView inherits from, and probably not what you're looking for in this case, since these views scroll with the tableview content, instead of appearing statically in place behind the table.

Comment: to set the image view as background of the tableview will make the (whole) image to be always seen, instead of the effect that I wanted to achieve (the tableview firstly cover portion of the image view, and the rest of the image view is only visible if pull down the tableview)

Comment: You mean add both subviews as what I did, and then set the background color of the table view as clear?

Comment: Yup, that should allow you to see the subview behind the tableview when dragging up or down beyond the table view's content.

Comment: I tried the approach, it shows the image view as the background of the tableview, which means that the whole image view could be seen at very first sight.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. Maybe you'll want to wait to add the background subview until you're done loading the data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just set the table view's .backgroundImage or .backgroundView properties to a `[UIImage imageNamed@"my image"];`